Windows: Calling w64devkit.exe with arguments from command prompt OR calling make on a Makefile (eventually from Jenkins)
I have successfully used the w64devkit (aka Mingw32) to make a Makefile for STM (firmware) code.  As you know, Windows doesn't have a native 'make' command.  Next up is to call this from a Jenkins Pipeline build.  To do this, it occurred to me to simple launch a command prompt (with 'bat') and then immediately launch w64devkit.exe and ask it to do the make.
How do I do this?  As an intermediate step, I'd like to simply launch a mingw window with a file of commands, or pass the commands in the command line from the command window (bat)
I have tried creating two files, run_64devkit.bat which looks like:
@echo off
set W64DEVKIT_PATH=C:\Dave\w64devkit-1.23.0\w64devkit\w64devkit.exe
set SCRIPT_PATH=C:/Dave/w64devkit-1.23.0/w64devkit/commands.sh
%W64DEVKIT_PATH% sh -c "sh %SCRIPT_PATH%"

This launches w64devkit.exe and runs commands.sh
sleep 10  # Delay for 2 seconds to ensure the environment is fully loaded
echo "Running commands in w64devkit"
gcc --version
echo "Done"
sleep 10  # Additional delay to ensure output is visible before exiting

The problem is that when I run: run_64devkit.bat from a command window, I simply go into the mingw shell ($ prompt) but the gcc version is not printed out or the "Running commands..."  What is going on?  Obviously, in the pipeline build script, I can't manually open a mingw window.
How do I solve this?  I should say, the end goal is simply to run make on an already existing Makefile on the agent machine (agent machine is Windows).  I'm not wedded to w64devkit, and other ideas are most welcome.

Have you tried launching sh -c ./commands.sh, documentation mentions it.

The author of w64devkit.exe was nice enough to answer an email. Here is a summary. Hopefully, he doesn't mind me quoting him:

While it may appear like a shell, w64devkit.exe is not itself a shell, but a small launcher to configure and start the real shell, which is sh.exe in the bin/ directory....
The launcher's job is to add its bin/ to the PATH, set a couple of
w64devkit-specific variables for your own scripts, then launch a login
shell (i.e. "sh.exe -l"). See src/w64devkit.c for details. The shell is actually the busybox-w32 "ash" app, and "sh.exe" is an alias command that seamlessly runs busybox.
All you really care about is the PATH part, which you can do yourself, especially since you already had to locate w64devkit.exe. Add its bin/ directory to your PATH yourself, then run "make" directly from whatever shell you prefer (cmd, ps, sh, etc.). You don't need w64devkit.exe, which is mainly for interactive use.
In other words, in your batch script or cmd.exe prompt:
set path=C:\Andrew\w64devkit-1.23.0\bin;%path%

Then you have access to "make" and such as normal commands. If you were to run "sh -l" from here, you'll get the same environment as the one provided through w64devkit.exe. See the "Usage" section of README.md.

For those looking for an example, I'd add that I set up a build.bat file very much like below, and it worked!  The key was the set path
@echo off
set path=C:\Andrew\w64devkit-1.23.0\w64devkit\bin;C:\ST\STM32CubeCLT\GNU-tools-for-STM32\bin;%path%


set MAKEFILE_PATH=C:\JenkinsHome\workspace\XXXXX\xxxxx-firmware\Source\Firmware\Projects\xxxxx2
echo %MAKEFILE_PATH%
make -j8 all -C %MAKEFILE_PATH%\AutomatedBuild
echo Done

